# Show null values in facet.pivot

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise, facet

I sent a Solr group query like

```
group=true&group.field=colorid
```

Some of the records are not assigned colorid and so they all are returned as null along with the count.
Now I have a pivot query like

```
facet=true&facet.pivot=colorid,featureid
```

This query does not returns me the count of the null colorids. Any help as to how can I get those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

facet.missing=true

It should show all the null values as one facet.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-Thefacet.missingParameter